# How to get skill ID from Alexa request in node.js

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am using node.js, Alexa sdk with express for handling requests and responses. How can I get skill id from the response which is alexa sending to my endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The skill Id is the application id inside the session object.

```
alexaResponse.session.application.applicationId
```